# Simpson's rule and Trapezoid Rule?

Tags: calculus, integration, numerical-methods

Let $S(n)$ and $T(n)$ be the approximations of a function using $n$ intervals by using Simpson's rule and the Trapezoid rule respectfully.

My book then states:

$$S(2n) = \frac{4T(2n) - T(n)}{3}$$

Can someone please give me a proof of this? I wasn't able to find one through Google.

Comment: What is your *definition* of the trapezoidal and Simpson's rule? Write these as summations over points in the interval, and see if you can manipulate the right side to get the left side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $x_0\le x\le x_0+2h$, where $h=(b-a)/(2n)$.  This will be one interval in  the trapezoidal rule for $n$ intervals, and so we have
$$T_1(n)=2h\frac{f(x_0)+f(x_0+2h)}{2}$$
for the trapezoidal approximation over this single interval.  The same interval counts as two intervals if we are looking at $2n$ intervals overall, so we then get the trapezoidal approximation
$$T_1(2n)=h\frac{f(x_0)+f(x_0+h)}{2}+h\frac{f(x_0+h)+f(x_0+2h)}{2}$$
and the Simpson's approximation
$$S_1(2n)=h\frac{f(x_0)+4f(x_0+h)+f(x_0+2h)}{3}\ .$$
It is easy to check that
$$S_1(2n)=\frac{4T_1(2n)-T_1(n)}{3}\ ,$$
and adding these for all $n$ intervals gives what you want.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!